# Android: Cannot input any digit in EditText field after leading minus sign

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have an EditText field whose input type is as follows:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

But after I type minus as the first character (leading minus sign) and then I try to input digit 2 but it is not taking it. In fact, after leading minus, it is not taking any input (no digits, nothing).

The other fields of EditText xml is below:

```
android:id="@+id/etAmount"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/editText"
android:longClickable="false"
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
```

Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a digits property for your editText and you can set the digits that you want to type only. This will help you.

```
android:digits="0123456789-"
```

Comment: I need decimal also. Then it will become android:digits="0123456789-.". And then an user can type .-.123 which is invalid and I will have to validate this in code and show the activity again. This is lot of work.

Comment: You can restrict a user from typing multiple times . in your editText. If user first times enters . you can replace it with an empty string. And until or unless the user enters the correct formatted input you can handle based on your requirements. Also if once . is entered, then if the user enters again you can then also replace . with "" and the process goes on. I can provide you this logic if you like. This way your work can be done

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved. There was an input filter in the code that was creating the problem.